# How to alter firewall (iptables) log rules such that they stop flooding the primary console on AlmaLinux 8?

Tags: centos, firewall, centos7, console, rhel8

I have a constant deluge of firewall blocks showing up on my console in AlmaLinux 8:
[image: firewall]

How do you modify `iptables` rules / settings so as to disable these from showing up on the primary console and to only render in log files?

Comment: Look here: https://superuser.com/questions/351387/how-to-stop-kernel-messages-from-flooding-my-console

Comment: Found this before your comment @NikitaKipriyanov with this same process (found from another forum), yet it's not ideal. Thanks for sharing that though. I'm still hoping to take another route insomuch that I only want to isolate this to firewall messages and to receive all others of all levels to the console.

Comment: Then reform a question for it to state this, instead of just "stopping". You can change iptables LOG rules to use another priority to be less than that is set in printk to print to console.

Comment: Et voila @NikitaKipriyanov

Comment: There's `NFLOG` btw.